# Looping through data in stored procedure in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a table `fpo` in which I have multiple fields and I am passing universe name `uname` while calling the stored procedure. Based on this universe name I need to concatenate different fields for different universe name to generate `universe key` and I need to push all these universe keys to json object, which I will use later in for loop in the same stored procedure.

I have written the below code, But it is returning only single universe key. Where as I have written limit 100 so it should return 100 values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file_compare(
    uname character varying,
    tb_name text)

    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    AS $BODY$
    declare 
    p_bene_first_name text;
    p_bene_last_name text;
    p_card_id text;
    p_auth_num text;
    p_date text;
    universe_key text;

    begin

    select bene_first_name, bene_last_name, card_id, authentication, created_date
    INTO
    p_bene_first_name ,p_bene_last_name, p_card_id, p_auth_num, p_date from fpo
    limit 100;


    IF (uname = 'UNI_1') 

    THEN

        SELECT NULLIF(p_card_id, '') || NULLIF(p_auth_num, '') INTO universe_key;

    ELSEIF (uname = 'UNI_2') 

    THEN

        SELECT NULLIF(p_card_id, '') || NULLIF(p_date, '') INTO universe_key;

    END IF;
    return universe_key;
    end;
$BODY$;
```

sample data

```
 bene_first_name  bene_last_name   card_id   authentication   created_date

     ABC               G             1256      2e4thjjk6        12/12/2018
     PQR               A             3456      h4j48545k        02/02/2019
```

According to my requirement I have to get the below after select and push it into some variable example fpo_json_data

```
 [{fname": "ABC","lname":"G", "cardid": "1256", "auth": "2e4thjjk6", "cdate": "12/12/2018"},{fname": "PQR","lname":"A", "cardid": "3456", "auth": "h4j48545k", "cdate": "02/02/2019"}]
```

Then I have to loop through fpo_json_data and create universe keys concatenating the fields and push these universe keys into another json variable Which I need to return

Comment: Can you also add a data sample and the exact expected result?

Comment: You are overwriting the variable in every iteration. But you don't need a (slow and inefficient) loop or even a function for this. This can be done with one single SQL query. Something like `select uname, concat(card_id, authentication) as universe_key
    from fpo
    where uname in ('UNI_1', 'UNI_2') limit 100;`

Comment: @JimJones I have edited my question and added expected result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to generate a json object because I will use it later

Comment: Still no need for a loop or a function: https://pastebin.com/raw/SzBzSEwx

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The link you mentioned is restricted for me

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a2ad775faa7b79bd01c804010400186f